# .NetCoreApp 1.1 - Default Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core Project Broken?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-1.1

I'm starting today to try and get to grips with the new .NET Core framework. So I installed **Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise** and .NET Core Workload as per the following link:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2017

I thought I would give a go at creating Class Library, so I created a new .NET Core Library project, which defaults to target framework **.NETCoreApp 1.1**:

[image: The following is taken from the project properties]

Now when the solution is created, the Nuget package restore fails for every package and not even **System** namespace is referenced correctly. FYI, the full error output for the restore can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/Qq82U8Gw) (pastebin).

Now if I can change the target framework to **.NETCoreApp 1.0** then the errors clear themselves up. So this is the confusion for myself a Core nOOb - I see 1.1 is available, but can i use it for Class Libraries or should i be targeting 1.0?

Also, my nuget source is the following:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

*UPDATE:*

I do seem to have the 1.1 SDK installed:
[image]

Comment: Did the project create a project.json file or csproj (super unlikely that it is project.json)? Is there any RC2 anything installed?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778143/mvc-package-not-compatible/40779107#40779107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I uninstalled all of the .NET SDK references (Windows: **Add or Remove Programs**) and re-installed .NET Core using the **Visual Studio 2017** workload using the **Visual Studio Installer**:

[image]

### **ReSharper Users:**

I had to open the Solution I have created, re-save it (for some reason), close Visual Studio, then re-open the Solution - this fixed issues with red squiggly lines everywhere and incorrect errors with **"Cannot reference...."**.